# Removing character between two special characters

Tags: regex, linux, sed, awk

I am trying to remove a string within two special characters.

```
cluster10619: negl|c55742_graph_c0_seq1:99:213:3:+ phar|comp52619_c0_seq1 pres|comp29354_c0_seq1 rugi|comp46514_c0_seq1
```

For example here I wanna remove everything between : and :+ so it would be

```
cluster10619: negl|c55742_graph_c0_seq1 phar|comp52619_c0_seq1 pres|comp29354_c0_seq1 rugi|comp46514_c0_seq1
```

Without changing the rest of the line (sometimes they are huge!)

I tried:  `sed "s/:.*:+//g"` but it removes the end of the line completely

Any ideas?

Comment: You should define a more general pattern. There are many `:` in your string, so should it be for example 1) after `seq1:`? 2) second `:`?

Comment: Yes directly after seq1, so removing everything after seq1, however sometimes it is not called seq1 but seq2 (I have 10000 clusters like this one!).

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS="|" '{sub(/:.*:\+/,"",$2)}7' file
```

test with your input:

```
kent$ echo "cluster10619: negl|c55742_graph_c0_seq1:99:213:3:+ phar|comp52619_c0_seq1 pres|comp29354_c0_seq1 rugi|comp46514_c0_seq1"|awk -F'|' -v OFS="|" '{sub(/:.*:\+/,"",$2)}7'
cluster10619: negl|c55742_graph_c0_seq1 phar|comp52619_c0_seq1 pres|comp29354_c0_seq1 rugi|comp46514_c0_seq1
```

Comment: @user3188922 run the awk line on your input file. check the output (stdout)

Comment: I did exactly this:awk -F'|' -v OFS="|" '{sub(/:.*:\+/,"",$2)}7' groups4.txt > out.txt

Comment: @user3188922 it would be ok.  any difference between in and output files? what did you mean "doesn't work"

Comment: Yes sorry I meant no differences at all

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed "s/:[0-9:]*:+//g" yourfile.txt
```